# Page doesn't load the correct CSS on live but works when testing on local

Tags: css, loading

Hi so I have this problem I keep not understanding... I've made a table in HTML with prices and stuff, everything looks good on my tests, but when I upload it on the main website, when I enter the website the changes are not applied, I try to apply mainly "width: 100%" and "height: 100%" so it will look good on phone, but changes don't seem to apply at all.

Comment: It's because its broken.

Comment: May be you got a life cache? then need to clear cache. Same for you browser just do a CTRL + F5 and the browser cache clear too.

Comment: Check your CSS file path in your master page / layour file. Make sure it is handled with an relative path so that it can do good at any condition.

Comment: Vidiya, how to make it with a relative path? is this not enough " <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">" ?

Comment: Nevermind, seems the clear of cache worked! Thank you!